# POSIX C interprocess communication (IPC) example works but shouldn't

Tags: c, ipc

I was testing out an example (from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ipc-using-message-queues/)) for IPC between two C programs running on the same machine. Here are the two mains for the message writer and reader:

bar.c (Writer)

```
// bar.c -- C Program for Message Queue (Writer Process)
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// structure for message queue
struct mesg_buffer {
   long mtype;
   char mtext[100];
};

int main()
{
   mesg_buffer message;
   message.mtype = 1;
   strcpy(message.mtext, "Hello Process!");

   // ftok to generate unique key
   key_t key = ftok("dummy.txt", 65);
   if (key < 0)
      printf("Bad key!\n");

   // msgget creates a message queue and returns identifier
   int msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

   // msgsnd to send message and echo to console:
   msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
   printf("Data send is : %s \n", message.mtext);
   return 0;
}
```

foo.c (Reader)

```
// foo.c -- C Program for Message Queue (Reader Process)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

// structure for message queue
struct mesg_buffer {
   long mtype;
   char mtext[100];
};

int main()
{
   mesg_buffer message;

   // ftok to generate unique key
   key_t key = ftok("dummy.txt", 65);
   if (key < 0)
      printf("Bad key!\n");

   // msgget creates a message queue and returns identifier
   int msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

   // msgrcv to receive message
   msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0);
   printf("Data Received is : %s \n", message.mtext);

   // to destroy the message queue
   msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

I ran the two programs but I got the "Bad key" error because I didn't have "dummy.txt" on the file system. Nevertheless, the programs continued and I got a good IPC:

```
penelope:~/test/build/bin$ ./bar
Bad key!
Data send is : Hello Process!
```

and in separate terminal:

```
penelope:~/test/build/bin$ ./foo 
Bad key!
Data Received is : Hello Process!
```

So even with the key error, I had successful IPC.

Now I define `dummy.txt` (I don't know why I need that) and run the pair again. `foo` and `bar` run without the "Bad key" error, but `foo` hangs waiting for communication.

In an effort to understand what `ftok` is doing, I changed those lines to the following:

bar.c: `key_t key = ftok(nullptr, 66);`

foo.c: `key_t key = ftok(nullptr, 65);`  <-- note different index

I get the "Bad key" error in both, but the IPC works. What's happening here? How are the two processes communicating here if the `ftok` key isn't even valid in the programs? And when the keys seem valid, it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look to the glibc source code you will see that `ftok` returns -1 if you don't provide a valid file:

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

key_t
ftok (const char *pathname, int proj_id)
{
  struct __stat64_t64 st;
  key_t key;

  if (__stat64_time64 (pathname, &st) < 0)
    return (key_t) -1;

  key = ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16)
     | ((proj_id & 0xff) << 24));

  return key;
}
```

> How are the two processes communicating here if the ftok key isn't
> even valid in the programs?

The function returns -1 to inform you that there has been an error but does not prevent its use as a (bad) key. In short, the key will collide with all programs that misuse the function, but both processes communicate because they are using the same key.

Comment: Good point. I was aware of the -1, but didn't consider that I was actually still using the key as -1 (or 0xff). Thanks. The question remains: when I did provide a valid filename, IPC reader hung waiting for the message.

Comment: Correction -- IPC reader is no longer hanging with good key. Problem solved.